# How can I make a phone call on Google Voice on a phone without mobile service?

Tags: google-voice

On an Andorid hone without mobile service, I try to use Google Voice to make a phone call in two ways:

- is it possible to make a phone call on Google Voice app? It always asks for verifying your own phone number and linking number.
- When I try to open voice.google.com on Google Chrome browser, and try to make a phone call, it asks "Google will call your phone and connect you to ...". (I used to have a mobile service, but now don't.)

How can I make either way work, without having a mobile service?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to Google, on Android in the GV app, you just have to open settings and under "calls" tap "Making and Receiving Calls" and select "Prefer Wifi and mobile data"

I THINK you might have to unlink your mobile number if it is still linked. If you don't have carrier service anymore, you should do this anyway. Has to be done through web browser, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Thanks. Why does Google Voice want to link phone number? I linked it to the phone number on a phone that I borrowed with mobile service. Do you mean that I should unlink it on that phone. I now want to use it on a phone without mobile service, besides the one that I borrowed.